# Emacsclient.exe -- How Load elisp from Command Line Argument --"-l" Option Not Recognized

Tags: emacsclient, command-line-arguments

Windows 7

emacs 28.2

Is there a way to load an elisp program from the command line when running the emacsclient?

emacsclient.exe doesn't recognize the "-l" command line option.

This works:  \runemacs.exe  \test.txt  -l "\elisp.elc"

This works:  \emacsclient.exe -n  \test.txt

This fails:  \emacsclient.exe -n  \test.txt  -l "\elisp.elc"

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, `-l` is only a command line option for `emacs`, not for `emacsclient`.

You can use this, however:

> ```
> -e, --eval    Evaluate the FILE arguments as ELisp expressions
> ```

E.g.:

```
emacsclient --eval "(load \"elisp.elc\")"
```

I believe you can't do that *in the same command* as visiting files, however, as `--eval` causes *all* file arguments to be treated as elisp, so you would need to issue two separate `emacsclient` commands.

Comment: Thanks!
Also, I found that two "eval"'s works.
E.g. to visit file test.txt, and then run blabba.elc on it:
\emacsclient.exe  --eval "(find-file \"/test.txt\")" --eval "(load \"/blabba.elc\")"

(Aside: I am not receiving notification of answers here.)

Comment: Good point, although note the description "Evaluate the FILE arguments as ELisp expressions" -- so you only need one instance of `--eval` (the second is redundant).